# Haagerup tensor product

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces. Recall that a closed subspace $V\subset B(H,K)$ is called a ternary ring of operators(TRO) if  $xy^*z \in V$ for all $x,y,z \in V$. Obviously a TRO is also a operator space.

> Let $V\subset B(H_1,K_1)$ and $W\subset B(H_2,K_2)$ be two TROs. We consider operator space Haagerup tensor product $V\otimes_{\rm h}W$ of operator spaces $V$ and $W$. It is well known that  $V\otimes_{\rm h}W$ is operator space. Is it true that  $V\otimes_{\rm h}W$ is also a TRO?

P.S: The same question was first posted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088645/haagerup-tensor-product) but I dint get any answer there.

Comment: No. Look at the row and the column Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: sorry but I don't understand how this example works as Haagerup tensor product of the column Hilbert space with the row Hilbert space is the space of compact operators which is also a TRO. Can you please explain?

Comment: Haagerup's tensor is not commutative.  Row tensored with Column is the space of trace class operators.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: But even trace class operators being a operator space is closed and also is an ideal so preserve ternary product? What am I missing?

Comment: The space of trace class operators with the trace norm is not a TRO.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: Do you have any counterexample in the case when $V$ and $W$ both are $C^*-$ algebras?